# How do I convert from stringstream to string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

How do I convert from `std::stringstream` to `std::string` in C++?

Do I need to call a method on the string stream?

Answer (score 294, accepted):

​​​​​​​

```
yourStringStream.str()
```

Answer (score 82):

Use the [.str()-method](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/io/sstream/str):

> Manages the contents of the underlying string object.
>
> 1) Returns a copy of the underlying string as if by calling `rdbuf()->str()`.
>
> 2) Replaces the contents of the underlying string as if by calling `rdbuf()->str(new_str)`...
>
> **Notes**
>
> The copy of the underlying string returned by str is a temporary object that will be destructed at the end of the expression, so directly calling [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) on the result of `str()` (for example in `auto *ptr = out.str().c_str();`) results in a dangling pointer...

Answer (score 19):

`std::stringstream::str()` is the method you are looking for.

With `std::stringstream`:

```
template <class T>
std::string YourClass::NumericToString(const T & NumericValue)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << NumericValue;
    return ss.str();
}
```

`std::stringstream` is a more generic tool. You can use the more specialized class `std::ostringstream` for this specific job.

```
template <class T>
std::string YourClass::NumericToString(const T & NumericValue)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << NumericValue;
    return oss.str();
}
```

If you are working with `std::wstring` type of strings, you must prefer `std::wstringstream` or `std::wostringstream` instead.

```
template <class T>
std::wstring YourClass::NumericToString(const T & NumericValue)
{
    std::wostringstream woss;
    woss << NumericValue;
    return woss.str();
}
```

if you want the character type of your string could be run-time selectable, you should also make it a template variable.

```
template <class CharType, class NumType>
std::basic_string<CharType> YourClass::NumericToString(const NumType & NumericValue)
{
    std::basic_ostringstream<CharType> oss;
    oss << NumericValue;
    return oss.str();
}
```

For all the methods above, you must include the following two header files.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
```

Note that, the argument `NumericValue` in the examples above can also be passed as `std::string` or `std::wstring` to be used with the `std::ostringstream` and `std::wostringstream` instances respectively. It is not necessary for the `NumericValue` to be a numeric value.

Answer (score 12):

From memory, you call `stringstream::str()` to get the `std::string` value out.